# ¿Error en mostrar datos al agregar un where en una consulta MySQLi?

Tags: php, mysqli

No me refleja los datos al agregar un `where` en una consulta MySQLi, si elimino el `WHERE` los datos se reflejan.

```
<?php
$stmt = $con->prepare("SELECT id_world,hour,date_matches,local,visitor,active FROM world WHERE active=? order by id_world ASC limit 5");
$stmt->bind_param("i",$active);

$stmt->execute();
$stmt->store_result();

if ($stmt->num_rows>0) {
  $stmt->bind_result($id_world, $hour, $date_matches, $local, $visitor, $active);
  while ($stmt->fetch()) {
    echo '<li><span>'.$hour.' '.$date_matches.'</span> '.$local.' <span class="color">Vs</span> '.$visitor.'</li>';
    }
  } else {
}
$stmt->close();
?>
```

Pueden explicarme porque sucede esto, no entiendo, la columna active, es numérica es decir y tiene valores numéricos en este caso es 1.

Comment: hay algun valor en i?

Comment: @gbianchi si el valor numérico de la columna active, yo tengo una columna denominada active donde aquel producto que tenga el valor 1 es mostrado si es 0 que no se muestre los productos, es así el procedimiento o no?

Comment: @gbianchi tengo ya un año que no programó nada :( esperó no me este olvidando.

Comment: Hola, ¿De donde proviene la variable `$active`?

Comment: La consulta en sí no tiene ningún problema, ni tampoco lo tiene el código. Si la variable `$active` es un valor proporcionado por el usuario, yo no renunciaría bajo ningún concepto a usar consultas preparadas. Si no envía datos puede deberse a otra cosa como: que el nombre de la tabla o de alguna de las columnas no esté escrito correctamente, que haya un problema con el dato que estás pasando en `$active`, que el `WHERE` no se cumpla para ese caso. Entonces depura lo siguiente: `var_dump($active);` Si es correcta, entonces copia la consulta y pruébala directamente en la base de datos.

Comment: @A.Cedano Todo funciona bien, al parecer hubo pequeño problema en el servidor local lo reinicie y ahora funciona.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Te recomendaría que usaras el select directo sin tener que usar bind_param.
En el caso de que active sea 1 o 0 y te interese sacar los que tengan 1 sería:

```
$stmt = $con->query("SELECT id_world,hour,date_matches,local,visitor,active FROM world WHERE active=1 order by id_world ASC limit 5");
```

En el caso de que incluso de esta forma no saque ningún resultado deberás comprobar que los campos que estás seleccionando sean correctos o bien cambiar todos los campos por un * y así recoger todos los datos.

```
$stmt = $con->query("SELECT * FROM world WHERE active=1 order by id_world ASC limit 5");
```

Comment: En caso de que la consulta no manejase ningún dato proveniente del exterior habría que usar `query` en vez de `prepare`. Como su nombre lo indica, este último es para consultas preparadas.